# How to remove lines that not containing any uppercase letters or lowercase letters or numbers notepad++ after ":"

Tags: notepad++, regex, notepad

I've never used a regex before.
I'm looking for a regex command that can help me bookmark lines AFTER ":" that has:

- at least 1 uppercase letter
- at least 1 lowercase letter
- at least 1 number OR special character ( Like `!,#,$,@` ).

Example:

```
x361:HDKS1a!
X73:HDKS1
X72:SSa$
X31:aa1$
x21:Sa123
```

Bookmarked Lines:

```
x361:HDKS1a!
X72:SSa$
x21:Sa123
```

Comment: Could you give sample lines and expected result? Your question is confusing according to the title, do you want to match lines that contain uppercase, lowercase and numbrers  or not?

Comment: Added example of bookmarked lines.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+:(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d!#$@]).+$`
- **CHECK** *Bookmark lines*
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    .+              # 1 or more any character 
    :               # a colon
    (?=.*[A-Z])     # positive lookahead, make sure we have an uppercase letter
    (?=.*[a-z])     # positive lookahead, make sure we have an lowercase letter
    (?=.*[\d!#$@])  # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit or a special char
    .+              # 1 or more any character
$               # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]